# Some characters become "�" in our webpage

Tags: php, string, encoding

I use PHP to access a database to get a string like this

> ‘Chloe’ Fashion Show & Dinner

and then I do a printf() to output the string as html, but my webpage shows this:

> �Chloe� Fashion Show & Dinner

All contents are English-based, do I miss something in PHP?

Where should I be checking?

Comment: Do you have the utf8 meta tag ?

Comment: Add utf8 meta tag in HTML page ..

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: Check for the document's character set. You can see and change with a code editor like "Notepad++". Try to convert utf8.

Comment: `mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8")` solves the problem, thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Check if your .php file is encoded as UTF-8 without BOM
2. Check that your **connection** to the database is UTF-8
3. Check that you send `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your HTML markup in the `<head>` tag

If your connection to the database is not UTF-8 and you don't want to change it (but I recommend it -> everything UTF-8 is the most secure solution against character rubbish) use [`utf8_encode($databaseValue)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) to ensure the encoding of your value is UTF-8.

Comment: I'd also check Apache/PHP config to send default charset utf8, mostly the problem is the first point you mention anyways, the file contents itself should be utf8 of course

Comment: I use `utf8_encode` and `�` characters are not there anymore. However, the original characters `‘` are gone too. It's kind of weird.

Comment: `mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8")` solves the problem, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you use:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

in the head of your page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add charset meta tag in 'head' section of html.
Note that the meta tag must appear within the first 1024 bytes of rendered page.

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
```