# Formatted text in posts like fb/orkut

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site under development.I have tried the following format in my post,but it doesn't display as it is.I have tested it in facebook/orkut which displays it as it is:

```
███─█─────█─███─███─███
█───█─────█─█───█────█
███─█──█──█─██──██───█
──█─█─█─█─█─█───█────█
███─██───██─███─███──█

███─███──███─███─██───█─███─
█───█─█───█──█───█─█──█─█──█
███─██────█──██──█──█─█─█──█
█───█─█───█──█───█───██─█──█
█───█──█─███─███─█────█─███─
```

But in my page it looks like the following while **retrieved** from database(MYSQL):

```
â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆ
â–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â”€â–ˆ
â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â–ˆ
â”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â”€â–ˆ
â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â”€â–ˆ

â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ”€
â–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â–ˆ
â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â–ˆ
â–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â–ˆ
â–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ”€â”€â”€â”€â–ˆâ”€â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ”€
```

If I preview it **without storing in database** using AJAX it looks exactly as it is. I have used the following PHP functions before storing into database:

```
    $content=$_POST['content'];
    $content = str_replace("<br/>","\n",$content);//br2nl
    $content=mysql_real_escape_string($content);
```

What should I actually do so that texts can be formatted this way as done in facebook or orkut etc?
Also I have used URL encoding before sending the text to the server:

```
var params = "content=" + encodeURIComponent(content);
```

Comment: This looks like an encoding issue. Try encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Check my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702687/some-characters-become-in-my-wepage/19702728#19702728

Comment: Thanks.@MarkusHofmann right, I have used URL encoding before sending the text to the server: var params = "content=" + encodeURIComponent(content); Should I use UTF-8 instead?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with URL Encoding. It's all about character encoding. To be able to display the chars correctly, use UTF-8. It'll work. See my answer.

Comment: @rosemary You're welcome :-)  Mind accepting my answer if it worked or ask me again if you need further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the charset meta tag into the header section of the html page where the special chars will be shown:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>...</title>
    ...
```

And encode the post before echo:

```
<?php
echo utf8_encode($postBody);
```

OR if the above does not work, try:

```
echo html_entity_decode($postBody, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

That should do the trick.

However, setting the database tables charset is recommended if you're storing the characters encoded in the db *(so you'd encode them prior to saving instead of afterwards when echo-ing)*:

```
ALTER TABLE posts CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

and if you want to set the default charset for sending data from and to the database use:

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); // Not available on Windows OS
```

Comment: Many many Thanks @Markus Hofmann , The second one works fine for me. In case of non-HTML5 browsers, should I use   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> instead ? outside <head> ?

Comment: I'd stick with the HTML5 Standard as it is future proof and _the old syntax is obsolete and no more recommended_. Also keep in mind that the `<meta charset="utf-8">` element must be inside the `<head>` element and within the first 512 bytes of the page as some browsers only look at these first bytes before choosing a character set for the page. See [this](https://code.google.com/p/doctype-mirror/wiki/MetaCharsetAttribute#Browser_compatibility) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset) for more details on browser compatibility and recommended usage.

Comment: I can't help saying thanks again kind heart @Markus Hofmann But for cross browser compatibility I should use <meta charset="utf-8"> as a fall back for the older browsers.Should I?

Comment: Some HTML entities such as &rsquo; and many don't need to be decoded in order to display from database (MYSQL),but this kind is really required,what happens exactly in database when it is stored and needs decoding?As I am new in this context,could you please mind to let me me know,because I am curious!

Comment: You shouldn't worry about browser compatibility too much. Stick with the new HTML5 Standard, as this is the way the future goes. The browsers [market](http://www.sitepoint.com/browser-trends-september-2013/) [share](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php) statistics show, that Google Chrome bit his way through its competitors and is used the most, followed by IE9+ and Firefox. You should suspend support for IE7 and lower. IE8 is still used, but the stats decline. So it's up to you (or your clients) whether to support IE8 or not. So: **Use HTML5 with e.g. [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com).**

Comment: Regarding the character encoding and its storage in the db: Store the data as pure as possible (that way you'll be able to change encoding of the data at all times). Then before you display the data on your page, encode it with the method above. It's best to use UTF-8 for this. It can represent every character in the Unicode character set and has backward compatibility with ASCII ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)). In case you receive user generated data, ensure the data will be sanitized (e.g. HTML Purifier) before being stored to avoid abuse. However, nothing is 100% secure.