# UTF-8 Encoding still wrong output

Tags: php, html, sql, encoding, utf-8

I have an encoding problem.

The table uses `utf8_general_ci`, the php header `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` and in the html the meta tag `<meta charset="utf-8">` is set. BOM is set right. The german chars are displayed right in phpmyadmin.

But when I output it the encoding results: Sask���

Any other idea what I can do?

Comment: Have a look at my answer in this question. It may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702687/some-characters-become-in-my-wepage/19702728#19702728

Comment: Oh thanks. utf8_encode() done it for me. Answer with it and I will accept :)

Comment: Well this is not worth an answer and should stay a comment. Cause your question is a possible duplicate of the question i linked to. Just give me an upvote there and all is fine :-). But propably you should set your **mysql connection charset** to mysql to UTF-8 instead of encode all the values to utf-8 (you can save a lot of time).

Comment: Ah yes, mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($link, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'"); helped. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solves the problem

```
mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysqli_query($link, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8'); // ← SOLUTION
mysqli_select_db($db, DB_NAME);
```